# Generating ctags tags inside vim within OSX doesn't work

Tags: macos, vim, ctags, exuberant-ctags

I'm using terminal vim in OSX and I've installed ctags via homebrew

then I have added the `/usr/local/bin/` directory to my PATH

and also aliased CTAGS to use the homebrew installed version

all of this in my .zshrc, and It works fine.

The problem is that when I try to run `:!ctags -R .` within VIM

It fails because it doens't recognized the option '-R'

I have runned `:!which ctags` and returns

```
/usr/bin/ctags
```

instead the `/usr/local/bin/ctags`

is any way to solve this?

**UPDATE**

I add my zshrc file

```
# number of lines kept in history
export HISTSIZE=1000
# number of lines saved in the history after logout
export SAVEHIST=1000
# location of history
export HISTFILE=~/.zhistory
# append command to history file once executed
setopt inc_append_history

autoload -U compinit
compinit

# Colors
autoload -U colors
colors
setopt prompt_subst

# Save a smiley to a local variable if the last command exited with success.
local smiley="%(?,%{$fg[green]%}☺%{$reset_color%},%{$fg[red]%}☹%{$reset_color%})"

# Show the relative path on one line, then the smiley.
PROMPT='%{$fg[cyan]%}%~ ${smiley} %{$reset_color%}'

RPROMPT='%{$fg[cyan]%} $(~/Dotfiles/rbenv-version.sh)$(~/Dotfiles/git-cwd-info.sh)%{$reset_color%}'

# Example aliases
source ~/Dotfiles/zsh/aliases
source ~/Dotfiles/zsh/plugins/bundler.zsh

export SHELL=/bin/zsh

export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

eval "$(rbenv init -)"

export LC_ALL=en_US.utf-8
export LANG="$LC_ALL"

export EDITOR=vim
### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Where did you add /usr/local/bin to your PATH? In .bashrc?

Comment: Make sure when you set the path that you added /usr/local/bin to the front of your path. Instead of the end.

Comment: @echristopherson it says `.zshrc` in the post

Comment: Can you post your zshrc or at least the relevant parts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what was the problem, accordingly to [this answer in superuser](https://superuser.com/a/47827)

> Vim 'ignores' your aliases because your shell is not in a 'mood' to
>   parse your .bash_profile/.bashrc (you did not specify, where your
>   aliases are defined) because it is not started as a login/interactive
>   shell (read here to find out more about what is read when and for what
>   reason).

and the solution for me was to set a global path like [described here](https://serverfault.com/questions/16355/how-to-set-global-path-on-os-x)

was to edit my `/etc/paths`

and add `/usr/local/bin` to the **beginning of the file** (in other case it doesn't work)

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```